# How do I create event between two projects?

Tags: c#, events

I created two projects(`Proj_1`,`Proj_2`), `Proj_1` contains `Proj_1_Program.cs` and `ProjectOneClass.cs`, `Proj_2` contains `Proj_2_Program.cs`,and I need `OnInformed` trigger both `Informed1` and `Informed2` this is how I got so far:

```
//Proj_1_Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CrossProjectEvent
{
    class Proj_1_Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProjectOneClass obj1 = new ProjectOneClass();
            obj1.Inform += new EventHandler(Informed1);
            obj1.InformNow();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Informed1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Informed1");
        }
    }
}

//ProjectOneClass.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CrossProjectEvent
{
    public class ProjectOneClass
    {
        public event EventHandler Inform;

        public void InformNow()
        {
            OnInformed(new EventArgs());
        }

        private void OnInformed(EventArgs eventArgs) // I want this method both trigger Informed1 and Informed2
        {
            if (Inform != null)
            {
                Inform(this, eventArgs); 
            }
        }
    }
}



//Proj_2_Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CrossProjectEvent;

namespace Proj_2
{
    public class ProjectTwoClass
    {
        public ProjectOneClass obj_proj_1;

        public ProjectTwoClass()
        {
            obj_proj_1 = new ProjectOneClass();
            obj_proj_1.Inform += new EventHandler(Informed2);
        }

        private static void Informed2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Informed2");
        }
    }

    class Project2
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

But it seems like only `Informed1` being triggered, so how to fix this? thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `Informed1` should not be triggered? What you want to get fixed? What do you want this code to do? Class `ProjectTwoClass` is nowhere used in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem requiring inter-process communication. There are a billion different techniques and approaches possible for it.

One solution would be to use Remoting using named pipes ([Sample](http://omegacoder.com/?p=101)), but also TCP and NetSockets are possible. This might be one of the simplest solutions.

If you are building a larger application requiring a lot of inter-process communication, the actor model, especially the [AKKA.NET](https://getakka.net/articles/intro/what-is-akka.html) libary, would be worth mentioning.

But these are just a few of the options you have.